# match everything except the regex pattern

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a xml content as below

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above i want to mach everything except **502 Bad Gateway** in title.

I used below regex to match **502 Bad Gateway**

```
(?<=title>)(.*?)(?=<\/title>)
```

Can someone tell me how to negate it?

I tried below suggestions

```
(?!((?<=title>)(.*?)(?=<\/title>)))
[^((?<=title>)(.*?)(?=<\/title>))]
```

But they didn't worked.

I am using ruby regex

Comment: Which language/regex engine are you using? It's recommended to include this information since the features are different among different regex engines.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to remove the title from the string? Then just use `re.sub` (or similar methods in other languages)

Comment: I am using ruby regex

Answer (score 0):

You want get everything that is not matched by the regEx?

Save your result with the language do you prefer.

Use some tools, for e.g.:

- WinMerge
- Beyond Compare
- KDiff3
- DiffMerge
- Merge
- ...

Some of them could generate a patch. Use File -> Open... to open the two versions for comparison. This will give you a nice view of what you have changed.  https://docs.moodle.org/dev/How_to_create_a_patch#Creating_a_patch_using_WinMerge

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `sub` to remove '502 Bad Gateway' in `title`:

```rb
xml = "<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>"
xml.sub("<title>502 Bad Gateway</title>", "<title></title>")
# => "<head><title></title></head>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very familiar with ruby but I assume the features of regex are similar with PCRE, which supports control verbs and recursion.

Here's the regex that matches your description:

```
((?<=title>)502 Bad Gateway(?=<\/title>))(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!(?1))[\s\S])+
```

See the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/iKyq6z/1)

Comment: Hi Hao Wu, This is working only for PHP<7.3.
But I am working in ruby regex engine, in which this is not working.